# How can I use FormLayout in Java Swing (JGoodies) in IntelliJ

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, jgoodies, form-layout

I'm really disappointed about that when I use Swing Java in "IntelliJ" it runs without any problem but when I use JGoodies… FormLayout
 it doesn't run with me and show error that:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jgoodies/forms/layout/FormLayout
```

This is the code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Adddata extends JFrame {
    private JPanel mainpanlll;

    public Adddata(String title )   {
        super(title);
         try {
            this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            this.setContentPane(mainpanlll);;
            this.pack();

        } catch (Exception e )
        {
            e.getMessage();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            JFrame frame = new Adddata("HI");
            frame.setVisible(true);
        } catch (Exception e )
        {
            e.getMessage();
        }
    }

}
```

and this is the error massage here[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CwXh.png)

Answer (score 1):

Ok finaly after 2 days searching it show that I must download 
jgoodies-common-x.x.x.jar and jgoodies-forms-x.x.x.jar
and add it to libary